# C++ Timer, Thread, periodic calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, timer

I have issue with thread-safe callbacks.

```
void draw_something() { /* draws something */ }
```

And the question is, how to call `draw_something` in main application thread every specify amount of time irrespective of other code(so it would act like C# Timer and fire function in main thread)? Earlier I was using CreateWindow to create(in main thread) auxiliary window which handles messages from SendMessage(which was sent from another timer-thread):

```
void MainThreadFunction(){
    CreateThread(0, NULL, GoProc, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

DWORD WINAPI GoProc(LPVOID lpParam){
    while(1){
        SendMessage(auxiliary_window_hWnd, ADDINATIONAL_MESSAGE, 0, 0);
        Sleep(30);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So window's MessageQueue deals safethread calls, but I don't think if it's very efficient and elegant way to do it. I know there is better way(maybe boost?) but I don't know it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Windows [`SetTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) call to get a periodic [`WM_TIMER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902.aspx) message and skip the second thread altogether.

Comment: +1 This will also prevent clock skew which the OP's code has. It will always have an interval of more than 30ms.

Comment: Timer can be subject to skew also. Doesn't look likely to be a problem for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just magically "interrupt" the running thread and "inject" your own code, not in the userspace anyway.

The solution you already have, which is essentially a form of [message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing), is fine if you don't have particularly strict temporal requirements.

If time *is* important to you, i.e. you have to guarantee certain latency between event (passage of time in your case) and processing of that event, you'll have to do the processing in the thread that "detected" the event or maintain a pool of worker threads ready to wake-up and do the processing on moment's notice. But I'm guessing `draw_something()` must be done on UI thread, so this solution is probably out.

Comment: Windows isn't well suited for hard latency requirements.